# Importing App into react js results on module error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im making a simple typescript project, but can't manage to solve the following error:

**Compiled with problems:
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 7:0-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in '/Projects/test/src'**

Any suggestions??

Here's the files..

Home:

```
import React from "react"

export const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <p>Essa é a pagina home</p>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Home } from './pages/Home';

export function App() {
  return (
      <Home />
  );
};
```

index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { App } from './App';

const ApplicationWrapper = () => {
  return (
    <App />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApplicationWrapper />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('main'),
);
```

FILE STRUCTURE:

[image: File Structure]

Answer (score 1):

When the code is exported and with a default keyword, that means you only can import by using import Alias from './module'. If you want to import through Object Destructuring, it needs to export a Component or module without using the default keyword.

Last line of Home component.

```
export { Home };
```

When it needs to import.

```
import { Home } from './path-to-component';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can export once at Home component like this:

```
import React from "react"

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <p>Essa é a pagina home</p>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: I removed the other export, applied ur suggestion but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, App.tsx file should be in index.tsx folder. ie both files should be in /Projects/test/src folder.

Comment: Both are already placed inside src folder :/
I update the thread with another print of my files structure

Comment: Can you check once replacing <App /> in index.tsx file with <div>test</div>. If it is working then issue in imports, otherwise there is issue in the app configuration.

Comment: It worked! But I couldn't manage to solve the import issue..